# Injected Angular 7 service has method set as undefined when called from Rxjs subscription handler

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, rxjs

I have seen other posts regarding this, however I have checked all other all suggestions, and I already have them in place.

I have an Angular 7 / Ionic 4 project where I have the following service:

```
    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })

    export class AppRoutingService { 
    ...
```

And this is declared in my core module:

```
    @NgModule({
      imports: [SharedModule, HttpClientModule],
      declarations: [],
      exports: [],
      providers: [
        ...
        AppRoutingService
      ]
```

I inject and use this service everywhere no problems. But, I have one case, where I want to use it from an Rxjs subscription.

The Rxjs `Subject` is within another service I use to monitor login state:

```
 export class LoginService {
      private loggedIn: boolean = false;
      
      public loggedInStateUpdate: Subject<boolean>;
```

And when the login state change, I just call next on this `Subject`.

Now, in the other area having the problem, I subscribe to this:

```
this.loginService.loggedInStateUpdate.subscribe(isLoggedIn => 
     this.gotoLoginPage(isLoggedIn));
```

The code to `gotoLoginPage` was just inline, but I factored into a method when having this problem. All it has is the following:

```
    private gotoLoginPage(isLoggedIn : boolean) : void {
        try {
          if (isLoggedIn)
            return;

          this.availablePagesService.currentPageRoutePath = Constants.vals.pageRoutePaths.login;
          this.appRoutingService.navigateRoot(Constants.vals.pageRoutePaths.login);  
        } catch (error) {
           this.logger.error(`gotoLoginPage: ${error}`);
        }    
      }
```

Now, the crazy thing is, suddenly the method I want to call is undefined!

[image]

And it was previously defined, as the code just before the subscription successfully called it:

[image]

If I look at my `this` in the vscode watch window, everything on my `this` looks as expected. All other injected services have all the internals defined as expected.

However, on this service, we can see the method `navigateRoot` is undefined, yet it shows up as a function in the `__proto__`.

[image]

I have never seen this before!

What could be wrong here? I don't see what the difference with this service is. It is declared, and provided in the `root`, just as most my other services.

Comment: remove providers[AppRoutingService] from root module and check

Comment: @Chellappan - do you mean remove the `providedIn: 'root'`? I tired this again (had previously) so I now just have `@Injectable()
export class AppRoutingService {
` but didn't make any difference. I still have the ` AppRoutingService` in the providers array for the `core.module` as I do all my other single app instant global singleton services. I do import `Router` into here (as I subscribe an monitor `this.router.events`), so not sure if this has anything to do with it, and why this particular services seems to behave differently to the others

Comment: @Chellappan - also did it the other way around (after re-reading your comment). So removed `providers[AppRoutingService]` and left in the `providedIn: 'root', but still no difference

Comment: did you initialise the subject with new key word?

Comment: Yes, in the `LoginService` constructor, I have `this.loggedInStateUpdate = new Subject<boolean>();`